# Автоматическая установка нужных модулей при запуске программы

Tags: python, library

Есть ли возможность, автоматической установки всех нужных библиотек, при запуске программы python?

Comment: это русскоязычный ресурс, тут принято вопросы задавать на русском языке

Answer (score 3):

```
from os import system

system("pip3 install numpy")
```

Вот к примеру код для установки numpy из кода программы

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Можно, самое простое это использовать виртуальные пространства и `pip`

1. Забрать все зависимости `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
2. Через `git` поддерживать актуальное состояние для данного файла
3. На целевой машине исполнять `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Автоматизировать при помощи скриптов, а на целевой машине можно использовать [`watchdog`](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) для мониторинга изменения зависимостей

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавлять библиотеки в Runtime’е используя pip, как это реализовано в [этом посте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234979/18375154):

Для pip позднее 10.x:

```
import pip._internal as pip

def import_lib(name):
    try:
        return __import__(name) # пытаемся импортировать
    except ImportError:
        pip.main(['install', name]) # ставим библиотеку если её нет
    return __import__(name) # возвращаем библиотеку

# Использование
if __name__ == '__main__':
    numpy = import_lib('numpy')
```